# Is is possible to submit data to a database without using PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, database, jquery, database-connection

I'm working in a third-party platform that doesn't allow PHP but I still need to submit information from a form into a database. So I need a way to submit data to the database without PHP.

Is this possible? Is there another route I could take for storing the information?

I've read a couple other posts but couldn't see a clear answer. This was the closest thing to what I'm trying to achieve I could think of... but not a route I can take.
[Directly accessing server database via Ajax (without PHP or some other intermediate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256310/directly-accessing-server-database-via-ajax-without-php-or-some-other-intermedi)

Comment: You have access to the server's database but not to actually put code on it? Can you put another language (Java, JSP, ASP, cgi, etc. etc.?)

Comment: We have access to the server, but the program that the code that we are creating is being placed in doesn't allow PHP. They said that several other clients have achieved this without PHP securely but haven't presented any examples. If I get anything I'll post a follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's simply that you can't use PHP, try using another platform.

Here are a few:

- Java Servlets - [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)

  - [JDBC basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/)
  - [Guidelines for Java Database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241454/best-way-to-manage-database-connection-for-a-java-servlet)
- Ruby - [Main website](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/)

  - [List of Ruby database adapters](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/SQL_Database_Adapters)
- ASP - [Main website](http://www.asp.net/) (microsoft servers only)

  - [How to use ADO.NET](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp)
- ColdFusion - [Main website](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family.html)

  - [How to connect to a database using coldfusion](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/database-connections-handled-coldfusion.html)

Obviously there are plenty of others. But you're going to need a server side programming language in there somewhere. If you try to connect to the database directly, your website is going to be woefully insecure.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you are not concern about security (you can use vbscript or shockwave or maybe just simply using javascript object notation), but if database is located on server don't you realize what disaster it will impact to your databases and website ?

PHP was created because of its simplicity on the language, I was code in perl before PHP 3 was released, it was a hard time to understand Perl syntax in CGI era. The main reason using server based script is the security of our database and our web stuff.

Do you want to develop third party platform ? 
maybe you can develop new kind of web browser technology with your new scripting on it, maybe your new platform will succeed.