# Connection Lost Error Tomcat 7

Tags: jsp

I am using Tomcat 7 in a server. That server will run always (it would be shutdowned). When I install tomcat it working fine (There is a login page which validates user id and password with mysql), but when I re login on next day it is throwing some error like,

**"No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error:..."**

When i login to server and restart apache tomcat then working fine.

So is there any way that to stop this error?. Can we do this at code level or server level (mean changing some settings etc?).

Please help I am at end of my project, errors like this are making me tense.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I have also same issue. please suggest. Thanks

Comment: What the mistake I have done is, I have not closed the connection after it used. So I have closed connection by using close() which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the database connection in your program. You can use [JDBC connection pooling](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html). 
You can use [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/).

Before any thing please take a look [Why connection pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241454/best-way-to-manage-database-connection-for-a-java-servlet#907320).

Comment: Any other alternative to this solution?