# Should I have a single database connection or one connection per task?

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, servlets, concurrency

I have a Java server and PostgreSQL database.

There is a background process that queries (inserts some rows) the database 2..3 times per second. And there is a servlet that queries the database once per request (also inserts a row).

I am wondering should I have separate `Connection` instances for them or share a single `Connection` instance between them?
Also does this even matter? Or is PostgreSQL JDBC driver internally just sending all requests to a unified pool anyway?

One more thing should I make a new `Connection` instance for every servlet request thread? Or share a `Connection` instance for every servlet thread and keep it open the entire up time?

By separate I mean every threads create their own `Connection` instances like this:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
```

Comment: Use a [connection pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc) and don't get caught up with Connection management. Solved problems are the best problems :).

Comment: Building on what @ProgrammerDan said, a lot of JavaEE servers have connection pooling built-in... you just have to do a JNDI lookup to get a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding,You should defer this task to the container to manage connection pooling for you.

As you're using Servlets,which will be running in a Servlet container, and all major Servlet containers that I'm aware of provide connection pool management.

### See Also

- [Best way to manage database connection for a Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241454/best-way-to-manage-database-connection-for-a-java-servlet)

Answer (score 4):

If you use a single connection and share it, only one thread at a time can use it and the others will block, which will severely limit how much your application can get done. Using a connection pool means that the threads can have their own database connections and can make concurrent calls to the database server.

See the postgres documentation, ["Chapter 10. Using the Driver in a Multithreaded or a Servlet Environment"](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/thread.html):

> A problem with many JDBC drivers is that only one thread can use a
>   Connection at any one time --- otherwise a thread could send a query
>   while another one is receiving results, and this could cause severe
>   confusion.
>
> The PostgreSQL™ JDBC driver is thread safe. Consequently, if your
>   application uses multiple threads then you do not have to worry about
>   complex algorithms to ensure that only one thread uses the database at
>   a time.
>
> If a thread attempts to use the connection while another one is using
>   it, it will wait until the other thread has finished its current
>   operation. If the operation is a regular SQL statement, then the
>   operation consists of sending the statement and retrieving any
>   ResultSet (in full). If it is a fast-path call (e.g., reading a block
>   from a large object) then it consists of sending and retrieving the
>   respective data.
>
> This is fine for applications and applets but can cause a performance
>   problem with servlets. If you have several threads performing queries
>   then each but one will pause. To solve this, you are advised to create
>   a pool of connections. When ever a thread needs to use the database,
>   it asks a manager class for a Connection object. The manager hands a
>   free connection to the thread and marks it as busy. If a free
>   connection is not available, it opens one. Once the thread has
>   finished using the connection, it returns it to the manager which can
>   then either close it or add it to the pool. The manager would also
>   check that the connection is still alive and remove it from the pool
>   if it is dead. The down side of a connection pool is that it increases
>   the load on the server because a new session is created for each
>   Connection object. It is up to you and your applications'
>   requirements.